# SQL Server: Incorrect syntax near 'DUMP'

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I have the below stored procedures to create database dumps in SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2016, these stored procedures already exist in a database and I am moving them to a different database

```
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[sp_univ_backupDB]'
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_univ_backupDB]

/*****************************************************************
* This proc is scheduled to run daily and creates a full database 
* backup of the following databases
*
*   Database    Device
*   ---------   -----------
*   Einvapp     einv_daily
*   Master      mst_daily
*
*****************************************************************/
AS
    DUMP DATABASE master TO mst_daily WITH INIT, SKIP
    DUMP DATABASE einvapp TO einv_daily WITH INIT, SKIP
GO

IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO

PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[sp_univ_backupMSDB]'
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_univ_backupMSDB]

/*****************************************************************
* This proc is scheduled to run daily and creates a full database 
* backup of the following databases
*
*   Database    Device
*   ---------       -----------
*   msdb        msdb_daily
*   
*   
*
*
*****************************************************************/
AS
    DUMP DATABASE msdb TO msdb_daily WITH INIT, SKIP
    DUMP DATABASE arceapp TO arceapp_daily WITH INIT, SKIP
GO

IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO

PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[sp_univ_backupTran]'
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_univ_backupTran]
/*****************************************************************
* This proc is scheduled to run hourly and creates a full transaction
* log backup of the following databases
*
*   Database    Device
*   ---------   -----------
*   einvapp 
*   Master      
*
*****************************************************************/
AS
    DECLARE @Hour CHAR(4),
            @DiskDev VARCHAR(20)

    SELECT @hour =  Right(+'00' + RTRIM(CONVERT(char(2),DATEPART(hour,GETDATE()))) +'00',4) 

    SELECT @DiskDev = (SELECT CASE @HOUR
                WHEN '0500' THEN 'tran_0500'
                WHEN '0600' THEN 'tran_0600'
                WHEN '0700' THEN 'tran_0700'
                WHEN '0800' THEN 'tran_0800'
                WHEN '0900' THEN 'tran_0900'
                WHEN '1000' THEN 'tran_1000'
                WHEN '1100' THEN 'tran_1100'
                WHEN '1200' THEN 'tran_1200'
                WHEN '1300' THEN 'tran_1300'
                WHEN '1400' THEN 'tran_1400'
                WHEN '1500' THEN 'tran_1500'
                WHEN '1600' THEN 'tran_1600'
                WHEN '1700' THEN 'tran_1700'
                WHEN '1800' THEN 'tran_1800'
                WHEN '1900' THEN 'tran_1900'
                ELSE 'NONE'
              END)

    IF @diskDev <> 'NONE'
            DUMP TRANSACTION einvapp TO @diskDev WITH INIT, SKIP
GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0 SET NOEXEC ON
GO
```

When I run the above script it fails in both SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2016 with these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_univ_backupDB, Line 25
>   Incorrect syntax near 'DUMP'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_univ_backupDB, Line 25
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_univ_backupMSDB, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near 'DUMP'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_univ_backupMSDB, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_univ_backupTran, Line 50
>   Incorrect syntax near 'DUMP'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_univ_backupDB, Line 26
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Can someone please help me to fix this SQL?

Comment: Do you mean BACKUP?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Is it supposed to be BACKUP instead of DUMP? These sprocs were intitially developed long back probably on `SQL Server 03 or 05`. Now we are migrating these sprocs to different database and am running it issues

Comment: I can't find a dump keyword for SQL Server searching the web. What version is the database you are currently migrating from?

Comment: I am finding some old threads online talking about DUMP being a valid command until it was removed in SQL Server 2008. I would think BACKUP would be the command you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you please share the threads talking about  DUMP being removed from SQL Server 2008 so that we document it and make the change to BACKUP. Also please post it as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some threads discussing this, but the usage pre-dates my time on SQL Server by a good bit. It appears that this was the command used prior to BACKUP; I can't find any site detailing how they are different.

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=200855

Answer (score 1):

Check original db for locations of these logical devices using `sys.backup_devices` catalog view.

There is no `DUMP` command in SQL Server. But, the scripts will work fine if you replace `DUMP` with `BACKUP` for database backups and with `BACKUP LOG` for transaction backup and if you have logical backup devices defined in new database.